# Iterate through all the photo library in iOS

Tags: image, objective-c, ios, framework

This function is supposed to return a map of all unique local identifiers of images that are on the iPhone using the IOS Photos Framework.

(it is a map so nSnull or (any object can be mapped to it) and retrieved in O(1))

I was never sure if in this way I am iterating every photos or am i missing something.

```
 - (NSDictionary*) getAllPhotos
        {
            PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
            if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
            {
                //initialize empty local state
                __block NSMutableDictionary* currentImageState = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
                @autoreleasepool
                {  
                    PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
                    userAlbumsOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedAssetCount > 0"];

                    //fetch all the albums

                    PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:userAlbumsOptions];
                    PHFetchOptions *onlyImagesOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
                    onlyImagesOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
                    onlyImagesOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];  
                    [userAlbums enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { 
                    PHFetchResult *collectionResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:onlyImagesOptions];

                    [collectionResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                            [currentImageState setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:asset.localIdentifier];
                        }];
                    }];

                    PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

                    [allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                         [currentImageState setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:asset.localIdentifier];
                     }];
                }
                return [currentImageState copy];
            }
            return 0;
        }
```